# Expo intent launcher custom Activity Action

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, expo

After new Expo SDK 43, IntentLauncher `startActivityAsync()` method is not accepting a string as parameter. Now, `ActivityAction` type is required.

How can I create a custom `ActivityAction`?

Expo SDK 42: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v42.0.0/sdk/intent-launcher/#intentlauncherstartactivityasyncactivityaction-intentparams

Expo SDK 43: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/intent-launcher/#intentlauncherstartactivityasyncactivityaction-params

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom activity you must first edit the AndroidManifest [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75013370/create-a-expo-config-plugin-file-to-modify-android-manifest/75907392#75907392)

Once the project is built just call the activity using startActivityAsync from the expo-intent-launcher library

```js
startActivityAsync(_ACTIVITY_ACTION_, params)
        .then((t) => {
          console.log(t);
        })
        .catch((err) =>
          console.error(
            `err: ${JSON.stringify(
              err.request
            )}`
          )
        );
```

Comment: OK but then how do you create the Activity java class itself and have it persist across builds? @nordy